# Replace certain character in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Now, before you say that this has been posted before, I have a different situation.

With that out of the way, let's get on with the question.

I am making a Discord bot for a friend that does duties for the group and things like that.

> Quick note too, I am using the [Sitepoint version](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/discord-bot-sitepoint) of Discord.JS because I'm a beginner.

I want the bot to send a message to a certain channel when the show gets canceled for a reason. For example, they would send something like this:

`afv!cancel Roblox went down.`

or something similar.

But every time it sends a message, every space turns into a comma like this:

`:x: The show has been cancelled because: "Roblox,went,down.". Sorry for that!`

Here's the index.js code that handles executing commands:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
  const args = msg.content.split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const prefix = command.startsWith("afv!");
  
  if (prefix == true) {
    console.info(`Called command: ${command}`);

    if (!bot.commands.has(command)) return;
    
    msg.delete(1);

    try {
      bot.commands.get(command).execute(msg, args, bot);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      msg.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    };
```

And the `cancelled.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'afv!cancel',
  description: "in-case the show gets cancelled",
  execute(msg, args, bot) {
    if (msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Bot Perms")) {
      const reason = args.replace(/,/g, " ");
      bot.channels.get('696135370987012240').send(':x: **The show has been cancelled** because: "' + args + '". *Sorry for that!*');
      bot.user.setActivity("AFV! | afv!help", { type: 'PLAYING' });
    } else {
      msg.reply('you are missing the role: Bot Perms!');
    }
  },
};
```

By the way, upon executing the command, it prints this:

`TypeError: args.replace is not a function`

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: seems like you need to conform your data structure to how it wants it. You could always convert to hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, here

```
const reason = args.replace(/,/g, " ");
bot.channels.get('696135370987012240').send(':x: **The show has been cancelled** because: "' + args + '". *Sorry for that!*');
```

you are making a `const` reason, wherein you try to handle that as a string and replace all commas with spaces. Unfortunately, even though it can be displayed in a string and looks to be one, in reality it is an array, so `replace()` won't work on it. To be able to use `replace()` you need to first transform your array to an actual string:

```
const reason = args.join().replace(/,/g, " ");
```

With that done you won't be seeing this pesky "not a function" error, and you can easily use `reason` to display your message:

```
bot.channels.get('696135370987012240').send(':x: **The show has been cancelled** because: "' + reason + '". *Sorry for that!*');
```

Comment: I actually am aware of that, but when I call the function replace(), it says `args.replace is not a function`. Sorry for not clearing that up!

Comment: What `args` actually is? Is it a string? Array? Object?

Comment: Look in index.js

Comment: ah, yes, of course. Okay, so here's what it looks like: `args` is an array of words. As an array, it doesn't have `replace()` method. When you concat it with string, it's displayed as one, but it actually isn't. So to perform any string operations on it, you need to use `join()` method first - and then replace. To sum up - change this `const reason = args.replace(/,/g, " ");` to `const reason = args.join().replace(/,/g, " ");`, and then use `reason` in your message. I also edited my answer above to make it more clear :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this later!